# WordPressエラーについて Notice: fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in

Tags: php, wordpress

ワードプレスでブログを作成していますが、突然、記事の編集や新規投稿ができなくなり、以下のようなエラーメッセージが出てきました。記事が編集＆新規投稿できるようリカバリーしたいです。

```
Notice: fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in/home/c7006248/public_html/ondine199918.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6574
```

サーバーはConoHa WING　、ブログテーマは、Affinger６を使用しています。
記事自体は閲覧することができます。
https://ondine199918.com/

エラーの住所にある通り、ConoHa WINGのファイルマネージャーでディレクトリ、ファイルをみてみました。

エラー行6574の表示は、

```
$file_data = fread( $fp, 8 * KB_IN_BYTES );
```

で、周辺コードは、

```
*/
function get_file_data( $file, $default_headers, $context = '' ) {
    // We don't need to write to the file, so just open for reading.
    $fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );

    if ( $fp ) {
        // Pull only the first 8 KB of the file in.
      $file_data = fread( $fp, 8 * KB_IN_BYTES );


        // PHP will close file handle, but we are good citizens.
        fclose( $fp );
    } else {
        $file_data = '';
    }
```

となっています。

どなたかお力添えいただけますと、幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：
現在のワードプレスのバージョンは5.9で、これがエラー発生前なのか後なのかは分からないです。

Comment: エラーが出るようになった前後で、例えば PHP や WordPress のバージョン等で環境に変更を加えたりしていますか？念の為それぞれのバージョン情報等も記載があると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: エラーに Is a directoryとあるのでデレクトーリーを読もうとしているかも、読み込むテーマ、プラグイン内の ファイルが破損したのでは？ テーマ、プラグインを一旦外して状況がどうなるか確認したらどうでしょう.

Answer (score 0):

@yyz さんの言っているように、ファイル（画像など）を指定しているのに、ディレクトリ(/で終わるURLとか)を指定してしまっていませんか？
**Notice**なので「致命的でないので今はとりあえずよしとする」という場合は、
一番最初のディレクトリにあるファイルwp-config.phpにある

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

を

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

にするととりあえず表示されなくなります。
解決方法が見つかったら直すとよいですね。